# Difference in expect statements makes no sense

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, expect

Using Jasmine/Protractor on an angular site, I'm running into an interesting issue when attempting to verify the selection I've just made in a dropdown.
The two dropdowns are virtually identical, with their page soure as follows below:

**GroupAssocDrpDwn Page Source:**

`<select class="pure-input-1 ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid length" id="groupAssociation" name="groupAssociation" ng-init="company.group.id = null" ng-model="company.group" ng-options="group as group.name for group in groups | orderBy : 'name'" ng-change="setStates(company.group)" has-value=""><option value="?" selected="selected"></option><option value="object:312" label="--No Group Association--">--No Group Association--</option><option value="object:313" label="Amicus Solar">Amicus Solar</option><option value="object:314" label="BakeryDirect">BakeryDirect</option><option value="object:315" label="Bicycle/Rumbleship">Bicycle/Rumbleship</option><option value="object:316" label="Brixy">Brixy</option><option value="object:317" label="NuORDER">NuORDER</option><option value="object:318" label="ProTradeNet">ProTradeNet</option><option value="object:319" label="Receivables">Receivables</option></select>
<option value="object:313" label="Amicus Solar">Amicus Solar</option>`
    *Etc...*

**StateDropdown Page Source:**

`<select name="state" ng-model="company.addresses[0].state" class="pure-input-1 ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" ng-options="state.abbr as state.name for state in states" ng-init="setStates()" has-value="" required="" style=""><option value="?" selected="selected"></option><option value="string:AL" label="Alabama">Alabama</option><option value="string:AK" label="Alaska">Alaska</option><option value="string:AS" label="American Samoa">American Samoa</option><option value="string:AZ" label="Arizona">Arizona</option><option value="string:AR" label="Arkansas">Arkansas</option><option value="string:CA" label="California">California</option><option value="string:CO" label="Colorado">Colorado</option><option value="string:CT" label="Connecticut">Connecticut</option><option value="string:DE" label="Delaware">Delaware</option><option value="string:DC" label="District Of Columbia">District Of Columbia</option><option value="string:FM" label="Federated States Of Micronesia">Federated States Of Micronesia</option>
<option value="string:FL" label="Florida">Florida</option>`
    *Etc...*

In a separate class, I have the two dropdown objects defined, calling the data I want to select from the dropdowns:

```
this.objAdminCompaniesGroupAssocDrpDwn = element(by.model('company.group'))
this.objAdminCompaniesStateDrpDwn = element(by.model("company.addresses[0].state"))

this.selectGrpAssocDropdown = function(value){
  return this.objAdminCompaniesGroupAssocDrpDwn.sendKeys(commonData.drpCmpnyGrpAssociation);
}

this.selectCompanyUSCAStateDropdown = function(value){
  return this.objAdminCompaniesStateDrpDwn.sendKeys(commonData.txtCmpnyState);
}
```

In the test _spec.js file, these are the calls to the functions (they are wrapped with Describe/It, not shown...).

```
adminAddCompany.selectGrpAssocDropdown();
expect((adminAddCompany.objAdminCompaniesGroupAssocDrpDwn).$('option:checked').getText()).toEqual(commonData.drpCmpnyGrpAssociation);

adminAddCompany.selectCompanyUSCAStateDropdown();
expect((adminAddCompany.selectCompanyUSCAStateDropdown).$('option:checked').getText()).toEqual(commonData.txtCmpnyState);
```

The EXPECT() on the first one (GroupAssocDrpDwn) passes fine. The EXPECT() on the second one does not; it fails with the error "*Failed: adminAddCompany.selectCompanyUSCAStateDropdown.$ is not a function*".
If, however, I put () at the end of that second call, like so:

```
expect((adminAddCompany.objAdminCompaniesGroupAssocDrpDwn()).$('option:checked').getText()).toEqual(commonData.drpCmpnyGrpAssociation);
```

. . . It now passes!

I'm not clear on why one would NOT require the function brackets, and one would...? (Note that the first one fails WITH brackets, also...)

Can anybody outline what the difference between these two expect() calls is, for a very curious human?

Thanks!

Comment: That error seems to be coming from the `adminAddCompany.selectCompanyUSCAStateDropdown();` call doesn't it? Does adding `()` where you said actually make things pass or does it cause a different error (perhaps that you have just missed)? Also you seem to have your "first" and "second" a bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objAdminCompaniesGroupAssocDrpDwn` and `objAdminCompaniesStateDrpDwn` are [ElementFinder](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder)s whose prototypes contain a [$](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$) function. So `objAdminCompaniesGroupAssocDrpDwn.$()` is legal.

`selectCompanyUSCAStateDropdown` and `selectGrpAssocDropdown` are simply functions that return a Promise. `$` is not a property on a basic Function prototype. So you would need to execute the function with `()` in order to get the underlying Promise.

What doesn't make sense here is calling `$` on the resulting Promise. Are you sure you're copying the error and your modified code correctly?

Comment: SkinnyJ you're right on it - thanks. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes... :-/  I was calling the function instead of the obj definition (which is what I really wanted). The below is correct and runs as expect()ed... `expect((adminAddCompany.objAdminCompaniesStateDrpDwn).$('option:checked').getText()).toEqual(commonData.txtCmpnyState);`